# iPhone won’t install previously deleted default app

Tags: ios-appstore

I’ve been trying to reinstall some default apps I had previously deleted such as “Watch” and “Files” through the App Store however with all of them I get the message:

> Unable to install ‘app name’ Please try again later.

All other apps download fine, it’s just the default Apple apps that won’t install.

Comment: What’s the version of iOS that you are running?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Your question is a bit confusing as you can't delete apps 'through the App Store' and there's no Apple default app named 'Watch'.  How did you delete these apps and how are you trying to reinstall them?

Comment: @fsb maybe I should've added a comma in my sentence. I said I'm trying to reinstall them through the App Store, I deleted them as you would normally with any other app. And yes, there is a default app called "Watch", it's the Apple Watch app that ships with every iPhone.

Comment: @Jarryd Oh yeah, I forgot about the Watch app.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting your iPhone. Sometimes rebooting it , helps.

Answer (score -1):

I found that resetting all settings in Settings>General>Reset sorted the problem out.